# Every 4-regular simple graph contains a 3-regular subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, problem-solving

The following result was conjectured by Berge & Sauer, and proved by Tashkinov [T].

**Theorem A.** Every 4-regular simple graph contains a 3-regular subgraph.

A simple graph is the one with no loops or parallel edges. I do not have access to Tashkinov's paper, so I don't know how the proof works. On the other hand, using Combinatorial Nullstellensatz, one can show the following:

**Theorem B.** Every 4-regular graph plus an extra edge contains a 3-regular subgraph.

I should note that Theorem B allows the graph to have multiple edges, so in particular, you are allowed to add an extra edge to a pair of adjacent vertices (so that there are now two edges between these vertices). The proof of Theorem B is a special case of $p=3$ in this [article here](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Choi.pdf) (see Theorem 2.5).

> Is there any easy way to use Theorem B to prove Theorem A?

It is tempting to add a random edge $e$ somewhere and use Theorem B to get a 3-regular subgraph. But then we have to somehow throw out that additional edge $e$. We may not be able to do this, as the edge $e$ could be an edge appearing in the 3-regular subgraph. Is there a way to get around this, or another trick?

[T] Tashkinov. Regular subgraphs of regular graphs. *Soviet Math. Dokl.*  **26**, (1982), 37-38.

P.S. I should add that if you know how Tashkinov's original proof goes, please feel free to add it as an answer! This would be very helpful too!

Comment: Other sources give the name as Taskinov, although I would transliterate it as Tashkinov.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't missquote. "Theorem" A would imply that every 4-regular graph has a perfect matching [make sure you see why]. However, $K_5$ is 4-regular, and does not contain a perfect matching, as it has an odd number of vertices.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your comment! I am fairly certain that this is the correct statement. For example, see the first sentence of the second paragraph of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.09384.pdf).

Comment: @Mike I still don't see why the Theorem A would imply that every 4-regular graph has a perfect matching. Could you explain what is the connection between containing a 3-regular subgraph and having a perfect matching?

Comment: @Prism My apologies for whatever reason I took it to mean that the 3-regular subgraph of a 4-regular graph $G$ would be on precisely the same vertex set as $G$, instead of a possible *proper* subset of the vertex set of $G$.

Comment: Accessing Tashkinov's paper [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01137412.pdf) requires only a SpringerLink subscription, but it's long and complicated enough I wouldn't want to write up an answer describing it; it's full of lemmas like "the minimal counterexample can't contain triangles" and "the minimal counterexample can't have any nontrivial 6-cuts", with no obvious main idea.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Thank you for the information, and correcting the spelling of the author's name. Yeah, I was able to see the article, and it is indeed quite involved. I wonder if there is a simpler proof using the polynomial method (Combinatorial Nullstellensatz or the like).

Comment: [This proof](http://www.cqvip.com/qk/86894x/198609/74888487495756544857484952.html) of Theorem A might be easier to follow; it's only in Chinese.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: My friend who speaks Chinese says that the article is not available through that link (when she clicked on download link, it said that the file does not exist).

Comment: @MishaLavrov The paper you mentioned is actually in English. The link you gave is to a Chinese abstract of it (kind of like Math Review), and the article can be found at http://caod.oriprobe.com/articles/33772845/EVERY_4_REGULAR_SIMPLE_GRAPH_CONTAINS_A_3_REGULAR_SUBGRAPH.htm, which is unfortunately after a pay wall. I've get access to a copy of it. It has 25 pages, and does not seem an easy read. I'm not sure which of the two proofs is easier to follow.